# How can I manipulate a website based on input from an android application?

Tags: android, server, web

I would like to make an app where when a certain action is preformed the person who downloaded the app can get money sent to them in the form of a gift card or pay pal. What I don't know is how to get the android app to preform that action. I know that apps can communicate with servers and that servers can give certain information to apps but I don't know how to make them preform an action like manipulating a website or even if they can. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what you need to get this working is to use an application programming interface (API). An API lets your program communicate with other programs such as PayPal. Your app will ask for PayPal for some data (perhaps an account number to send the money to) and PayPal will send a response. This response will either be a success message or a failure message depending on how PayPal's API handles your request. The way that these messages are sent and received is via HTTP Requests. If everything goes smoothly, your app will talk back and forth with PayPal's API.

You will need to do more research on this topic to understand all the concepts involved. You may want to start by looking into the HTTP request life cycle, and RESTful API.